# Report Menu disabled for Azure database

Tags: database, azure, report

When I right click on any azure DB the "Report" menu is disbaled (unable to click). We can click and view "Report" for master DB but not for any user DB. The SSMS version used is v17.1.
I am logged in as using server admin.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the latest SSMS from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017), Currently, I have the SSMS Version of 17.7 I can able to see the `Report` menu for myself

`MasterDB`

[image]

`UserDB`

[image]

Comment: I can also see Report enabled for Master database but not for any user DB. will check if we can incorporate latest version of SSMS in our citrix app menu. Thanks!

Comment: @KamleshBhat I can able to see the reports in my User DB as well. See the Updated Answer above. Try to update the SSMS as I said

Comment: @KamleshBhat Is the above help for you. Then mark it answer so that It's helpful for the other community members

Comment: Sry for no update. But i am unable to get latest SSMS Version in our citrix app suit to check and verify. Will definitely update if I get it or find any other solution.

Comment: You need Windows Platform to support the latest SSMS.